# Calculating the chance Y will happen when there are multiple chances Y can happen

Tags: statistics

If there is X% chance Y can happen one way and there is Z% chance Y can happen another way, then what is the chance that Y can happen? X=50%, Z=70%, the outcomes are not mutually exclusive of each other, these two outcomes are the only possible ways that Y can happen.

Comment: what are the weights for each of the other things happening ?  ...

Comment: Doesn't sound like there is enough information unless you make some assumptions (e.g. independence) about whatever events the $X\%$ and $Z\%$ refer to.

Comment: Not enough information.  If the possible outcomes are mutually exclusive then the answer is $x+z$, but you did not specify this.

Comment: X% = 57% and Z% = 70%; the outcomes are not mutually exclusive

Comment: the outcomes are independent of each other

Comment: Please edit the question to include all the relevant information, don't leave it to the comments.  Are these two outcomes the only possible ways that $Y$ can happen?

Comment: I believe that all you are after is the basic rule $P(A\cup B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cap B)$.  Here, since you have independence, $P(A\cap B)=P(A)\times P(B)$.  But, really, your question lacks details so I may be guessing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

here is a hint as to why people may be telling you you don't have enough information given. It's like if a pharmacy student asked, I have a 57% solution and a 75% solution ( weight/weight for simplicity) what percent solution will I get if I completely mix the two, without relative volume of each solution you can get any answer in between the two solutions you want a 1 to 1 ratio will give a 66% solution a 2 to 1 mixture of the two ( in the same order as given) will give a 63% solution a 1 to 2 ( again in the same order given)  will give a 69% solution. etc.